# Other name for D minor on C

Tags: chords, chord-theory, harmony

How would one call a Dm with a C bass?

I was wondering as it consists of the 2nd, a suspended 4 and the 6th so should the name be C 2/6 suspended 4?

Comment: This "auto chord namer" [website](https://www.scales-chords.com/findnotes_en.php?n1=C&n2=D&n3=F&n4=A&n5=&n6=&optbass=1&piano=1) might help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slash chords don't always need to be given more specific names, but if you do try to find another name for **Dmin/C** then the context will matter. This could be just a **Dmin** with a C in the bass, i.e. a **Dmin7** in third inversion. This probably makes sense if the C is part of a bassline.

If it makes sense to think of this chord as having a C root for some reason, then maybe it would be fine to call it a **C6(sus2)**, or better a **C6/9(sus4)**.

If **Dmin/C** does not sound like a D minor chord, it seems like a better name would be **F6**, since the notes of this chord (C D F A) form an **F6** in second inversion.

Answer (score 6):

Dm with a C bass note will usually be written as **Dm/C**. It's the third inversion of D minor seventh. You state that it *is* Dm, so unless that's inaccurate, Dm/C (or Dm7/C as a faint possibility) is good.